# how to find the POST or GET variables posted by mechanize (python)

Tags: python, forms, post, get, mechanize

i'm using mechanize to submit a form like this...

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('http://stackoverflow.com')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['q'] = "test"
br.set_handle_robots(False)

response = br.submit()

print response.info()
print response.read()
```

using firebug i can see that the actual variables posted are:

q   test

how can i retrieve these programatically using my python script?

please note i'm not actually scraping SO - just using it as an example!

also, i know in this case the posted variables are obvious, since there's only the one i specified - often this is not the case!

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print br.form.get_value('q')
```

Comment: ah - thanks - that works great for getting the hidden form variables, do you have any idea how to access the cookie/session info?

Comment: cookies will be in the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable debug mode in mechanize by putting this:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_debug_http(True)
...
```

Hope this can help :)

Comment: yes, that does help, thanks! - i can now see the variables going out... any ideas how to get to them from the mechanize.browser object? :)

Comment: Sorry but i don't think so , and if you want to save the debug info or something, i don't know an easy way to do this, because this function enable the debug info to be print in the sys.stdout but i think what you can do it to capture the output to be put in a file by redirecting the sys.stdout to a file or if you want you can also create a class or a function(decorator maybe) that capture this info and save it in an attribute that you can add to browser instance or to a new class that you can create for this purpose ... hope my explanation can help :)